Why does the .push() method take &mut Vec<T> instead of taking ownership of Vec<T> (followed by returning it back)?
The .push() method on Vec<T> takes as its argument a &mut Vec<T>, and the addition of the new element is a side effect.
What is the reason it was decided against push to be purely functional such that its API would look this:
fn push(mut self, elem) -> Self

Would taking ownership of the Vec<T> not be ergonomic in some way?  I do not believe there to be a substantial performance hit by moving it, given that Vec is just a fat pointer.

Generally it's most ergonomic to require the least privileges for example you can't easily use your implementation when you only get a &mut Vec<T>

Moving may cost. Maybe a little bit but nonzero. Plus returning Self may prevent some optimizations, since then compiler may no longer assume it is the same object, unless inlining happens.

How would you add new element to a Vec if it is a part of another struct?

So that you can push to a &mut Vec<_> you have been given?

The whole point of functional interfaces is to create a new object, hopefully that shares a lot of common with the old object to make the whole operation efficient, so that you can also reuse the old one. But this is impossible here due to move semantics of Rust, so there is little point IMO in having such an interface.

@Dmitry You could deconstruct the struct, push, reconstruct. But yes I think this make it clear that &mut Vec<T> is much more ergonomic than taking and returning an owned value each time.

You can't deconstruct struct if it implements Drop.

@Dmitry Would you add your comments as an answer?  I think it is the correct one which I'd like to mark as accepted.  Thank you

Taking a mutable reference is more flexible but nothing prevent you from making your own trait and implement it for vector.
pub trait Acc {
  type Item;

  fn acc(self, item: Self::Item) -> Self;
}

impl<Item> Acc for Vec<Item> {
  type Item = Item;

  fn acc<'a>(mut self, item: Self::Item) -> Self {
    self.push(item);
    self
  }
}

Personally I define this in one of my library:
/// Abstracts something which can push Item into self
pub trait Push {
  /// Item stocked in the collection
  type Item;
  /// Represent a way to access Item in the collection directly after push
  type ItemView<'a>
  where
    Self: 'a;

  /// push an item into a collection, no guarantee on ordering.
  fn push<'a>(&'a mut self, item: Self::Item) -> Self::ItemView<'a>;
}

/// This is very usefull to be use on combinator like fold.
/// For example, `.fold_bounds(.., Vec::new, Acc::acc)`.
pub trait Acc {
  /// Item stocked in the collection
  type Item;

  /// Accumulate item into Self. For example, for a vector that simply a push.
  fn acc(self, item: Self::Item) -> Self;
}

impl<T> Acc for T
where
  Self: Push,
{
  type Item = <T as Push>::Item;

  fn acc(mut self, item: Self::Item) -> Self {
    self.push(item);
    self
  }
}

